# postgresql 9.4 installation on GNURoot Debian v0.6.7_armhf

Tags: debian, android, postgresql

postgresql 9.4 installation on [GNURoot Debian](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gnuroot.debian&hl=en) v0.6.7_armhf

```
#service postgresql start
[warn] No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster" ... (warning).
```

Tried to resolve using `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and selecting locale and after

```
#pg_createcluster 9.4 main --start
Creating new cluster 9.4/main ...
config /etc/postgresql/9.4/main
data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main
locale en_US.UTF-8
Flags of /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main set as -------A-----e-C
FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=1, size=40, 03600).
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main"
Error: initdb failed
```

On trying to create user, I also have tried changing postgresql port number same output with different port number.

```
#createuser user -P -S -R -D
Enter password for new role:
Enter it again:
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

netstat output

```
#netstat -plunt
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State          PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN         28433/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN         28433/sshd
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42110         :::*                    LISTEN              -
udp6       0      0 :::546                  :::*                                        -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android intentionally does not support SysV shared memory `shmem` or POSIX `/dev/shm` and instead created `/dev/ashmem` ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/4e159d95ebf23b5f72bb707b0cb1518ef96b3d03/docs/system/libc/SYSV-IPC.TXT)).
But Postgresql needs SysV shared memory to work.

This github project might be a solution :
https://github.com/pelya/android-shmem

This library enables the use of shared memory in android across independent processes using shmget(), shmat() and shmdt() API's seamlessly.

Read the release notes for using the package. Although dating from two years ago
it is still [reported as working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40644816/165358).

If the release notes are not enough, I have also found
[this advice](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy/issues/29) :

> To install (in chroot environment):
>
> ```
> cp libandroid-shmem-gnueabihf.so /lib/libandroid-shmem-gnueabihf.so
> ```
>
> To start a program :
>
> ```
> env LD_PRELOAD="/lib/libandroid-shmem-gnueabihf.so" program %u
> ```